# Loop within a function: Local variable assigned but never used

Tags: python

I found many topics about this issue but I can't get my code to work.
It works perfectly by itself:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"

try:
    request = requests.get(url) 
    if request.status_code == 200:
        website_is_up = True
except:
    website_is_up = False
```

But when I try to insert the code in a function, I am getting the message: Local variable website_is_up is assigned but never used:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"

def test():
    try:
        request = requests.get(url) 
        if request.status_code == 200:
            website_is_up = True
    except:
        website_is_up = False
```

I am using try/except because others statements lead to errors (because of requests).

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you're not in fact using the value of the `website_is_up` variable anywhere; the warning is right about that

Comment: As the message indicates, you have assigned `website_is_up` but have not used it anywhere else in your code. Maybe try to write the rest of your code and that message won't be there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `website_is_up` in `test()` function, you can simply return `website_is_up` just to avoid the `error`.

You haven't called your `test()` function at all, try using the below code...

```
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com"

def test():
    try:
        request = requests.get(url) 
        if request.status_code == 200:
            website_is_up = True
    except:
        website_is_up = False
    return website_is_up
    
print(test())
```

Answer (score 1):

`website_is_up` is in the [scope of the function](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/) (it is not accessible outside the function). If you neither use it in your function (after you created it) nor return it then this assignment has virtually no effect.